# Formatting a numeric vector: Aligning to decimal points

Tags: r, vector, formatting

Given a numerical vector I want to convert it to a character vector given a maximum with of usable characters.

```
x = c(2, 0.002, 0.2)
x
# [1] 2.000 0.002 0.200
```

The print method for example works quite as I want the formatting to be. If the space is not sufficient or the other way around it should behave as follows:

```
myFormat(x, width = 4)
# "2.00" "0.00" "0.20"
myFormat(c(2, 0, 0.2), width = 4)
# " 2.0" " 0.0" "0.2"
```

Is there a simple way to do this with `prettyNum`, `formatC` or some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try `sprintf`. It uses a format like c's `sprintf`, e.g. from `?sprintf`:

> ‘m.n’ Two numbers separated by a period, denoting the field width
>             (‘m’) and the precision (‘n’).

```
sprintf("%4.1f", x)
# [1] " 2.0" " 0.0" " 0.2"

sprintf("%5.2f", x)
# [1] " 2.00" " 0.00" " 0.20"
```

Comment: Some kind of intelligent determination of how many decimals are needed before and after the point would be nice.